# conditions doesn't work on hasMany association using contain in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I am trying to search on several conditions on Users Model and Addresses Model. Here Addresses Model are associated with Users Model in hasMany relation. Any condition on Users Model working fine but not working in Addresses Model. Here is my code snippet.

```
 $this->hasMany('Addresses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'LEFT'
    ]);
$this->belongsTo('Users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ]);

$options = array();
    $status = $this->request->getQuery('status');
    $options = array_merge(array('Users.status' => $status), $options);
    $profile = array();
    $phone = $this->request->getQuery('phone');
    $profile = array_merge(array('Addresses.phone' => $phone), $profile);
    $addressArr = array('Addresses.user_id', 'Addresses.mobile', 'Addresses.phone', 'Addresses.country_id', 'Addresses.state_id', 'Addresses.city', 'Addresses.zipcode', 'Addresses.address_line1');

    $uses = $this->find('all')
        ->select(['Users.id', 'Users.user_type_id', 'Users.first_name', 'Users.last_name', 'Users.email', 'Users.image', 'Users.status', 'Users.social_type'])
        ->contain([
            'Addresses' => function ($q) use ($addressArr, $profile) {
                return $q->select($addressArr)->where($profile);
            }
        ])
        ->where($options)
        ->offset($offset)
        ->limit($limit)
        ->toArray();

    return $uses;
```

Comment: Please share your UsersTable, AddressesTable and ProfilesTable model code also so that it can be checked whether the association is according to Cake's convention or not. Also please share the result you getting from query here.

Comment: probably you need to use `matching`, see if this answer could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50510241/cakephp-3-orm-producing-allowed-memory-size-exhausted/50512548#50512548